# Why do C standard libraries neglect const correctness?

Tags: c, string, constants, const-correctness, ctype

Looking at most of the functions in the C standard libraries, there appears to be a lack of const, where specifying so, would normally be preferred.

For example:
**ctype.h/c**

```
extern int isupper(int __c) __ATTR_CONST__;
extern int islower(int __c) __ATTR_CONST__;
extern int isdigit(int __c) __ATTR_CONST__;
```

Why aren't these instead:

```
extern int isupper(const int __c) __ATTR_CONST__;
extern int islower(const int __c) __ATTR_CONST__;
extern int isdigit(const int __c) __ATTR_CONST__;
```

They only observe the parameter after all:

```
int isupper(int c) {
  return _pctype[c] & _UPPER;
}

int islower(int c) {
  return _pctype[c] & _LOWER;
}

int isdigit(int c) {
  return _pctype[c] & _DIGIT;
}
```

---

Or let's take a function in **string.c**:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count)
{
         char *tmp = dest;
         const char *s = src;

         while (count--)
                 *tmp++ = *s++;
         return dest;
}
```

Why not:

```
void *memcpy(void *const dest, const void *const src, size_t count);
```

Is const excluded in these places for a reason?
Would it be wrong to include const in the ways I've shown?

I assume the functions have remained this way for historical reasons,
but I figured I should ask in case I've missed something.

Comment: That implementation of the `memcpy` function you show is how beginners do it, it's not very optimal and a release build of a program using `memcpy` will not use such a naive implementation (unless the compiler and standard library is very stupid). As for the character classification "functions" they may be implemented as macros and as such can not have const-correctness.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, I didn't write it.  That's what was in my newly installed linux distro's system files.

Comment: What he's hinting at is that professional solutions would likely utilize the whole copy power of the processor. For example they could use `uint_fast8_t` instead of char, and then decrease `count` by `sizeof(uint_fast8_t)` instead of 1. It seems strange to me that you would find such a naive implementation inside Linux somewhere, `memcpy` would typically be integrated in the compiler.

Comment: Btw correct library implementations would also use `restrict` pointers. Similar to "const correctness", there also exists "restrict correctness", whenever you write a function which does a copy between two memory locations. ISO C requires that memcpy has the following definition: `void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);`

Comment: I was hoping this question was asking about functions like `char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);`  which return a `char *` form within `const char *s1`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those *are* `const`-correct signatures.

You almost never write `const` before pass-by-value arguments.
The function gets its own copy so there's no danger there.

The implementation of the function *could* make a promise to itself not to modify the parameter `int isupper(const int c){ ... }` and the compiler would enforce it to help the implementation with its logic, but that top-level qualifier is not part of the function signature and it is fully compatible with `int isupper(int);` (applies to top level `volatile` and `restrict` too).

```
 int isupper(int);
 int isupper(int const); 
 //fully compatible prototype -- top level qualifiers are not
 //part of the function signature
```

`void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count)`  is `const`-correct too. Only the second pointer promises not to change what it points to. The destination pointer, on the other hand, is all about changing what it points to.